Angular 17: Angular function guard inject() inject new instance of service
I have an Angular functional guard (CanActivateFn) that needs to update/access a value in a service. Unfortunately, that service does not act as a singleton: a new instance is injected each time the functional guard is executed.
Here's the guard code:
const myAppGuard: CanActivateFn = (route, state) => {

  const uiService : UiService = inject(UiService);

  // proof that this is a different instance, UiService runs
  // Math.random on instantiate
  const uiServiceVersion = uiService.serviceInstance;

  const router : Router = inject(Router);

  const appInit : boolean | null = uiService.appInit;
  if (!appInit) {
    uiService.appInit = true;
    return router.createUrlTree(["/home"]);
  } else {
    return router.createUrlTree(["/browserclose"]);
  }

};

The Ui service definition shows that it's provided in root :
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UiService {

  serviceInstance : number = Math.random();
  appInit : boolean | null = null;

That service is not specified by any providers array.
I'm guessing this is stupidity on my part, or it might be early and the coffee hasn't kicked in yet.

could you share a stackblitz highlighting the issue happening

Ended up solving the issue using session storage. Would have preferred a smaller hammer, but it worked.

providedIn: 'root' = app.module.ts -> providers.
If you need same service somewhere in code when remove "providedIn root".
app.module.ts:
export const SST = new InjectionToken<UiService>('UiService'); 
providers: [..., { provide: SST, useClass: UiService}, ...]

Now you can inject service by token and update some data in it.
